# Ignore DOI in elsarticle documentclass

Tags: natbib, elsarticle, doi

MWE:

```
\documentclass{elsarticle}
\bibliographystyle{elsarticle-num}

\begin{document}
    \cite{auth1}

    \section*{References}
    \bibliography{mybibfile}
\end{document}
```

This creates perfect pdf but with DOI in the reference. I tried to add the following:

```
\usepackage[backend=biber,
   natbib=true,
   sorting=none,
   doi=false,
   isbn=false,
   url=true,
]{biblatex}
```

But this gives some error, probably due to the `elsarticle` document class.

What to change in my `tex` file so that `doi`, `isbn` does not appear in pdf.

Comment: The `elsarticle` class uses `natbib` not `biblatex`, and as it's for publication you 'take what you get' in terms of DOIs and the like, normally.

Comment: If you are publishing with Elsevier you should not modify the output their templates give (after all, they are their templates). If you do not plan to publish with any of their journals, why do you use their heavily-customised class in the first place?